# How to prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n}r^n = 0$ for $|r| < 1$?

Tags: calculus

Let $|r| < 1$. How can I prove that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n}r^n = 0?$$

I’ve tried taking logarithms and using l’hopital’s rule but am not really getting anywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By ratio test we obtain

$$\left|\frac{\sqrt{n+1}r^{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}r^n}\right|=\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot |r| \to |r|<1$$

and we can conclude.

As an alternative, using logarithm we obtain

$$\log \left(\sqrt{n}|r|^n\right)=\log \left(\sqrt{n}\right)+\log \left(|r|^n\right)=\frac12 \log n+n\log |r| =n\left(\frac12 \frac{\log n}n+\log |r|\right) \to -\infty$$

therefore

$$\sqrt{n}|r|^n=e^{\log \left(\sqrt{n}|r|^n\right)} \to 0$$

Comment: Ah, so this proves that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{n}r^n$ converges, which implies that the limit of the terms goes to zero. Is there a more direct way to do this without invoking series?

Comment: @TheProofIsTrivium I've added another way but consider that ratio test also holds for sequences, we don't need series to invoque that.

Comment: Just saw your edit, thank you.

Comment: @TheProofIsTrivium Refer to [that](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-ratio-test-for-sequence-convergence).